# What's happening to my blueberry leaves?

Tags: identification, blueberries

I just planted these blueberries, and they looked perfectly healthy beforehand. Here's what the leaves look like now:

[image: Maybe fungus]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DXUK.jpg

Is this just transplant shock? Should I remove the affected leaves?

Zone 8B

Comment: Are they in full sun now? Do you know if they were in full sun at the nursery/garden center, or partially protected by shade cloth?

Comment: @csk these were thinned from a wild/native open field. I would call it partially shaded but very minimally, more like they were kind of covered in grape vines. but no overhead shade. They're in similar shade conditions now, on the north side of my house, they probably get 6-8 hours of sun.